# How to Print Crown Input to Console in WatchOS 6

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos-6

I'm trying to print crown input in Apple Watch and I can't get it to work.

I have created a new watch app (for watch only).

I have this in my HostingController:

```swift
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class HostingController: WKHostingController<ContentView>, WKCrownDelegate {

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        print("awake")

        crownSequencer.delegate = self
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

        print("willActivate")

        crownSequencer.focus()
    }

    func crownDidRotate(_ crownSequencer: WKCrownSequencer?, rotationalDelta: Double) {
        print("\(rotationalDelta)")
    }

    override var body: ContentView {
        return ContentView()
    }
}
```

In the console "awake" and "willActivate" are both showing up. But when I am rotating the crown nothing shows up.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a lot of digging and testing I solved this.

The crown **will register movements in WKInterfaceController class** extension and not in WKHostingController that I was referring to in my question.

I am very new to watch development so I can't figure out why is this happening, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

As you are using `WKHostingController`, you will need to use the swiftUI API's for the digital crown. It appears the standard (old) API just fails silently.

You will need a `@State` variable to bind the crown to, to make ui element focusable and to add the crown modifier.

```
@State var rotationValue = 0.0

var body: some View {
    Text("Crown did rotate: \(rotationValue)")
        .focusable(true)
        .digitalCrownRotation($rotationValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, if you use a swiftUI solution, you are supposed to use `combine` to perform the communication, i.e. monitoring the crownSequencer  value.